# django queryset method on related model filter

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-managers

I have the following set-up:

```
class Person(models.Model):
  name

class AppointmentQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
  def active(self):
    from django.utils import timezone
    return self.filter(initial_date__date__lte=timezone.now().date())

class Appointment(models.Model):
  initial_date = models.DateTimeField()
  person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='appointments', blank=True, null=True)
  objects = AppointmentQuerySet.as_manager()

  def active(self):
    from django.utils import timezone
    return self.initial_date <= timezone.now().date()
```

I fired up the shell to try some queries and created:

- 1 `person` with no `appointment`s
- 2 `person` with 1 `active` `appointment` each

and tried this:

```
Person.objects.filter(appointments=True) 
# At some point yesterday, this was giving me results, 
# now it's returning an empty queryset
```

this works as I thought it would:

```
Person.objects.filter(appointments_isnull=False)
# returns the 2 persons with appointments but
# I have no clue from here if the appointments are active or not
```

If I try `Person.objects.filter(appointments__active=True)`, I get:

```
FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: appointments
```

If instead, I try `Person.objects.filter(appointments.active()=True)`, I get:

```
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

How can I filter from `Person.objects.filter(appointments=?)` the active `appointment`s each `person` has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving it creating a PersonQuerySet and a method, like so:

```
class PersonQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
  def active_appointments(self):
    from django.utils import timezone
    return self.filter(appointments__initial_date__date__lte=timezone.now().date())
```

It kinda sucks having to duplicate code tho.